# Having trouble creating a dot drawing program and casting

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics, casting, mouseevent

Trying to do a mouse event assignment. The idea is that when the user clicks the mouse the program draws a small green dot, when the mouse is released it should create a small orange dot 5 pixels down and 5 pixels right of it. The assigment requires the three programs, Dots, DotsPanel, and DrawDots. The program should also have a counter of total dots. Right now the programs compile, but the program completely breaks and gives me tons of errors when I try to run it. I'm a bit lost right now as I'm new to this GUI and user mouseEvents. Thank you! I specifically have trouble of how to get past the casting the Dots class as a Point.

Here is a copy of the instructions:

Modify the “Dots” example.  Include a Dots class that contains a constructor to initialize the color and point location of the dot.  The Dots class should also include two accessor methods.  The ArrayList will now contain a list of the dots to draw instead of points.  When the mouse is pressed, the program draws a green circle (as in the original design).  When the mouse is released, the program draws a yellow circle translated 5 pixels right and 5 pixels down from the released location.  Be sure to keep track of the total number of dots.  You should have three files: Dots, DotsPanel, DrawDots. (10 points)

```
/**
 * @(#)Dots.java
 *
 *
 * @author
 * @version 1.00 2015/5/16
 */
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;



public class Dots
{
    Point p;
    Color col;

    public Dots(Color c, Point x)
    {
        p=x;
        col=c;
    }


    public Point getPointP()
    {
        return p.getLocation();
    }

    public Color getPointC()
    {
        return col;
    }

}
```

....

```
//represents the primary panel for the Dots program on which the
//dots are drawn

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DotsPanel extends JPanel
{
    private final int WIDTH = 300, HEIGHT = 300;
    private final int RADIUS = 6;

    private ArrayList<Dots> pointList;
    private int count;

    //Sets up this panel to listen for mouse events.
    public DotsPanel()
    {
        pointList = new ArrayList<Dots>();
        count = 0;

        addMouseListener(new DotsListener());

        setBackground(Color.black);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    }

    //Draws all of the dots stored in the list
    public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
    {
        super.paintComponent(page);


        //Retrieve an iterator for the ArrayList of points
        Iterator pointIterator = pointList.iterator();

        while(pointIterator.hasNext())
        {
            page.setColor(Color.green);
            Point drawPoint = (Point) pointIterator.next();
            page.fillOval(drawPoint.x - RADIUS, drawPoint.y - RADIUS,
                            RADIUS * 2, RADIUS * 2);


            page.setColor(Color.yellow);
            Point drawPoint2 = (Point) pointIterator.next();
            page.fillOval(drawPoint2.x - RADIUS+5, drawPoint2.y - RADIUS+5,
                            RADIUS * 2, RADIUS * 2);
        }

        page.drawString("Count: " + count, 5, 15);
    }

    //represents the lister for mouse events
    private class DotsListener implements MouseListener
    {
        //Adds the current point to the list of points and redraws
        //whenever the mouse button is pressed
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
        {
            Dots dot1 = new Dots(Color.GREEN, event.getPoint());
            pointList.add(dot1);
            count++;
            repaint();
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event)
        {
            Dots dot2 = new Dots(Color.YELLOW, event.getPoint());
            pointList.add(dot2);
            count++;
            repaint();
        }

        //Provide empty definitions for unused event methods
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {}
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {}
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {}
    }
}
```

.....

```
//demonstrates mouse events and drawing on a panel
import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawDots
{

    //Creates and displays the application frame
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame dotsFrame = new JFrame("Dots");
        dotsFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        dotsFrame.getContentPane().add(new DotsPanel());

        dotsFrame.pack();
        dotsFrame.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

Comment: What are your errors

Comment: @kon http://i.imgur.com/B8KBPc2.png  ,Here's a screenshot of all the errors. This is after clicking the mouse once, so one release and one press

Answer (score 0):

First you should use `Iterator<Dots> pointIterator = pointList.iterator();`. This helps the compiler to warn you in case of uncastable types (this is the first error you got). In your `paintComponent` method you should use `Point drawPoint = pointIterator.next().getPointP();` and `Point drawPoint2 = pointIterator.next().getPointP();` a view lines later.
After that modifications the program runs (at least on my machine).